# Apache POI - CellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT

Tags: java, excel, maven, apache-poi, xls

I am trying to align text.
Here my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
```

in my code:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
```

but when I want to use it (`CellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT`) , I got this compilation error:

[image]

Comment: Provide us the full usage of `CellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT`, please.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for

```
cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
```

Answer (score 9):

```
XSSFFont font = workBook.createFont();
Old : font.setBoldweight(XSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
New : font.setBold(true);

also 

CellStyle style = workBook.createCellStyle();
OLD : style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
New : style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

then
style.setFont(font);
```